# Error message when trying to manually input a donation in civicrm

Tags: civicontribute

I am trying to input a manual donation payment (ACH transaction) for a current member in civicrm and keep getting the following message:
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. DB Error: unknown error

Can you help me to problem solve?[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxkB2.jpg)

[image: Add Payment form]

Comment: Can you please check the Civi log /files/civicrm/Configlog/.